# How to send a object and a variable on Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I try this it works perfectly:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=product/product/quoteProduct',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product select),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Now I want to send a variable with the object `$('#product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product select)`. I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=product/product/quote',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    quantity: quantity, 
    option: $('#product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product select')
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

However, my console warns:

> TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Comment: You're trying to pass a jQuery object `$('#product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product select')` while you should probably pass only the `.val()` of that element

Comment: But i have multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're sending jQuery object in an AJAX request. Given the comment under the question you state that you want to send their values only, which can be achieved using `map()`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=product/product/quote',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    quantity: quantity,
    option: $('#product :radio:checked, #product select').map((i, el) => el.value).get(),
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Note that you can alternate `"` and `'` quotes in order to avoid having to escape then in a sequence. You can also use `:radio` in place of `input[type="radio"]`.

Comment: How can I get the name too?

Comment: You can't if your intention is to send an array of string values. You'd need to amend the JS and your PHP to send/receive an array of objects instead.